# Cannot register at Facebook Messenger with telephone number

Tags: 8.1, facebook, lumia-925, messenger

I would like to use Facebook Messenger on my Nokia Lumia 925 (Windows Phone). I downloaded the app, installed it, but now it is asking me to create a Facebook account instead of letting me register with a phone number. I cannot get anywhere near to phone number registration.

Only options:

- Log in with Facebook
- Not on Facebook yet? Leads to registration page

I never had Facebook and not going to create account just to use this app!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true that you can use messenger app without a facebook account but the WP app does not support that functionality. You may consider creating a facebook account. That's not a very big deal. Otherwise you can't use messenger

Answer (score 0):

You need a Facebook account to use Facebook Messenger, so your options are:

- Create a new account through the registration page you mention

or:

- Don't use Facebook Messenger.

Comment: Actually, you don't need a Facebook account to use Messenger: https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2015/06/sign-up-for-messenger-without-a-facebook-account. It just looks like the WP app was never updated to support registering with a phone number.